# invalid object name master~1 in our Jenkins is causing infinite version bump

Tags: git, jenkins, git-clone, fastlane, shallow-clone

We haven't changed anything in our Jenkinsfile or Fastfile, however all of a sudden we're seeing this in our logs.

> invalid object name master~1

It's causing an infinite auto-bump.

We use this function in our Fastffile to check whether or not we should bump the version or not.

```
def should_bump_version
    last_changes = `git diff podspec HEAD~1`
    !last_changes.lines.any? { | line | line.start_with?("+") and line.include?("s.version") }
end
```

Comment: Any chance you'd be willing to share your Jenkins file? We are wanting to setup Jenkins but really are not clear how to or what we can do with it. We just have an empty Jenkins file and I've been trying to find something that has something like auto versioning and pushes after testing.

Comment: @Elijah My apologies, for security reasons I'm unable to do that. That being said I recommend that you use Fastlane if possible. It makes your life a whole lot easier

Comment: @Elijah Take a look at the GitHub repos from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_and_open-source_iOS_applications). These are open source projects that you can use for inspiration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from colleagues and shout out to [Liam Nichols](https://twitter.com/liamnichols_) we realized that someone had switched our Jenkins configuration to a **shallow clone** and that was causing a boolean check to return `true` when it shouldn't i.e. as soon as we do:

```
HEAD~1
```

it results in the following error being returned to its next line.

It was producing an error because with a shallow clone, the previous commits were not part of the clone. This made `HEAD~1` undefined. Hence the error:

> invalid object name 'master~1'

This caused the `should_bump_version` function to incorrectly return `true`. And obviously Jenkins runs on every commit, so we were in an endless loop.

We avoided this by setting the shallow clone depth to 5 in our Jenkins configuration. The reason that we initially changed this was that some repo's git clone was huge and this was done to save us some size.